# Form data submitting multiple times and PHP not sending data messages with form POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Trying to make a really simple form. Im using Jquery Ajax to send a POST request to a PHP page which then writes the form data to an SQL database as well as returning success / error messaging which should be displayed through a javascript alert.

The alert always gives an undefined message.

As an additional slightly weird issue further submissions of the form seem to increase the actual submissions of the form by one each time (without page refresh, 2nd submission will send data twice, 3rd submission will send 3 times etc). This is probably not a mission critical issue as realistically i would never be allowing a user to send this form more than once without a page refresh, however for my own learning (and sanity!) id really like to get to the bottom of why its doing this.

This is very possibly a very simple issue, and if so i apologise in advance.. first time ive attempted server communication.

Thanks a lot for your help and if any additional information is needed, please let me know :)

**code**

**HTML**

```
<form id ="zombieForm" method="post">


     <select name="multi1">         
<option value="4">placeholder value 4</option>
<option value="3">placeholder value 3</option>
<option value="2">placeholder value 2</option>
<option value="1">placeholder value 1</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
<p>placeholder</p>
<select name="multi2" required>
    <option value=""></option>
<option value="4">placeholder value 4</option>
<option value="3">placeholder value 3</option>
<option value="2">placeholder value 2</option>
<option value="1">placeholder value 1</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
<p>placeholder 2</p>
    <select name="multi3"> 
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="4">placeholder value 4</option>
<option value="3">placeholder value 3</option>
<option value="2">placeholder value 2</option>
<option value="1">placeholder value 1</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
<p>placeholder 3</p>
    <select name="multi4">
        <option value=""></option>
<option value="4">placeholder value 4</option>
<option value="3">placeholder value 3</option>
<option value="2">placeholder value 2</option>
<option value="1">placeholder value 1</option>
</select>
    <br><br>
<p>placeholder 4</p>
    <select name="multi5">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="4">placeholder value 4</option>
<option value="3">placeholder value 3</option>
<option value="2">placeholder value 2</option>
<option value="1">placeholder value 1</option>
</select>
    <br></br>
      <p>placeholderbool1</p>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="4" checked>yes
        <br></br>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1">no
<br><br>
    <p>placeholderbool2</p>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="4" checked>yes
        <br></br>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="1">no
<br><br>
<p>placeholderbool3</p>
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="4" checked>yes
        <br></br>
<input type="radio" name="radio3" value="1">no
<br><br>
<p>placeholderbool4</p>
    <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="4" checked>yes
        <br></br>
<input type="radio" name="radio4" value="1">no
<br><br>
<p>placeholderbool5</p>
    <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="4" checked>yes
        <br></br>
<input type="radio" name="radio5" value="1">no
<br><br>    

        <p>Gender</p>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>Male
        <br></br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
      <br><br>
<p>Where are you from?</p>
<select name="location">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Asia">Asia</option>        
<option value="Africa">Africa</option>
<option value="Antartica">Antartica</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Europe">Europe</option>
<option value="North America">North America</option>
<option value="South America">South America</option>
</select>
      <br><br>
<p>How old are you?</p>
<select name="age">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="<18">Under 18 </option>
<option value="18-25">18-25 </option>
<option value="25-40">25-40</option>
<option value="40-50">40-50</option>
<option value="50+">50+ </option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id ="formButton">
</form>
```

**Javascript (using Jquery 2.1.4 and Jquery validate 1.14.0)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("jquery ready");
    // jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    //    debug: true
    // });
    var form = $("form");
    form.validate();
    $("#formButton").click(function () {
        var isValid = form.valid();
        if (isValid) {
            alert("Valid: " + form.valid() + "form validation passed");
            var frm = $('#zombieForm');
            frm.submit(function (ev) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "form_validation.php",
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.error) {
                            alert("error" + " " + data.error);
                        } else {
                            alert("success" + data.message + " " + data.sql);
                        }
                    }
                });
                ev.preventDefault();
            });
        } else {
            alert("form validation failed");
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "server";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";
$multi1 = $_POST[multi1];
$multi2 = $_POST[multi2];
$multi3 = $_POST[multi3];
$multi4 = $_POST[multi4];
$multi5 = $_POST[multi5];
$radio1 = $_POST[radio1];
$radio2 = $_POST[radio2];
$radio3 = $_POST[radio3];
$radio4 = $_POST[radio4];
$radio5 = $_POST[radio5];
$gender = $_POST[gender];
$age = $_POST[age];
$location = $_POST[location];



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO zc_Answers(dateCreated, multi1, multi2, multi3, multi4, multi5, radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4, radio5, gender, age, location) VALUES (Now(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");



$sql->bind_param("iiiiiiiiiisss", $multi1, $multi2, $multi3,  $multi4,  $multi5, $radio1, $radio2, $radio3, $radio4, $radio5, $gender, $age,  $location); //s = string, i = number
$sql->execute(); //execute the query;
$sql->close(); //close the statement.

if (!$sql) {
echo json_encode(array("error" => $sql , $conn =>error));

} else {
 echo json_encode(array("message" => "New record created successfully"));
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

**EDIT console.log(data) data **

```
"<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
  </head>
  <body>

Notice: Use of undefined constant multi1 - assumed 'multi1' in /var/form_validation.php on line 11

Notice: Use of undefined constant multi2 - assumed 'multi2' in /var/form_validation.php on line 12

Notice: Use of undefined constant multi3 - assumed 'multi3' in /var/form_validation.php on line 13

Notice: Use of undefined constant multi4 - assumed 'multi4' in /var/form_validation.php on line 14

Notice: Use of undefined constant multi5 - assumed 'multi5' in /var/form_validation.php on line 15

Notice: Use of undefined constant radio1 - assumed 'radio1' in /var/form_validation.php on line 16

Notice: Use of undefined constant radio2 - assumed 'radio2' in /var/form_validation.php on line 17

Notice: Use of undefined constant radio3 - assumed 'radio3' in /var/form_validation.php on line 18

Notice: Use of undefined constant radio4 - assumed 'radio4' in /var/form_validation.php on line 19

Notice: Use of undefined constant radio5 - assumed 'radio5' in /var/form_validation.php on line 20

Notice: Use of undefined constant gender - assumed 'gender' in /var/form_validation.php on line 21

Notice: Use of undefined constant age - assumed 'age' in /var/form_validation.php on line 22

Notice: Use of undefined constant location - assumed 'location' in /var/form_validation.php on line 23
{"message":"New record created successfully"} 

  </body>
</html>
"
```

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yeah good point, its a bad habit

Comment: php never told your browser that it's sending json text, so it'll have gone out as `content-type: text/html`, and the ajax code accepts that as-is. either tell is you're expecting json, or do a `JSON.parse(data)` first. doing `console.log(data)` should confirm that you've got a simple string reponse, which happens to contain raw json.

Comment: @MarcB doh, seems a really simple mistake! Where would be the best place to do the parse?

Comment: `success: function(data) { decoded = JSON.parse(data); }`

Comment: @MarcB hmm im now getting a syntax error in the JSON data:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

want me to post the updated code block?

Comment: `console.log(data)`, and see what came through. note that ANY php errors/warnings output by your scripts will cause the json to be "corrupted".

Comment: @MarcB ill post it as an edit, there quite a bit.

Comment: just the relevants bits are needed, especially whatever comes before/after the json data.

Comment: @MarcB oops read that too late. Well im guessing its the HTML declaration and all this notice guff that is causing the issues? Is there any way to filter this out so its only sending the actual JSON response?

Comment: yeah. anything OUTSIDE of `<?php ... ?>` code blocks is simply output. your php script can't output ANYTHING other than the json_encode() output, otherwise it'll be corrupted json.

Comment: @MarcB Okay ive removed the HTML markup, its still writing the notices though. Im guessing these are being thrown in the first place because the variables are undefined at the top of the script? Would declaring these after the initial SQL connection be viable?

Comment: You need to do your post as $_POST['multi1']

Comment: `$multi1 = $_POST[multi1];`. array keys must be quoted when used like this: `$_POST['multi']`.

Comment: Thats got it! :) thanks a lot for your help. Its still doing the weird double/triple/quadruple submission if i submit before a page refresh though. Any idea what would be causing this? (from the cause of the last bug, im guessing its something really simple im missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is resolved in the comments section. Many thanks to marc B for helping me with this.

the multiple form issue is to do with the "submit" event binding multiple times to the form after submission. I havent quite figured out why its doing this but a simple solution is to unbind then rebind the event before the ajax function. This seems to have resolved it:

changed:

```
var frm = $('#zombieForm');
            frm.submit(function (ev) {
                $.ajax({
```

to

```
 var frm = $('#zombieForm');
$(frm).unbind('submit').bind('submit',function(ev) {
                               $.ajax({
```